# Problems using webcam in python, openCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

```
File "C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I uninstalled opencv-python and re-installed it again

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you do not have conflicting versions of numpy in different locations in storage as this seems that the issue is not cv2 but numpy, which is needed when making use of the opencv library